# Extending Django templates with a form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

I have a simple note taking part of my application that I want to combine into one html page. One page has the form to submit the notes, while the other displays the results. I'd like to have both the form and results on the same page.

I'm attempting to use Django's template inheritance to achieve this, but the results aren't working as planned. When using it the way (obviously improperly) I have, the results do not show up and only the "submit" button from the form is displayed; not the actual form.

This should be fairly simple but I've tried several variations and researched potential solutions and template documentation for hours with no success.

If there's anyone who can illustrate what I'm doing incorrectly, it would be very appreciated.

Here's the code with the basic form template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block page_title %}Notebook{% endblock %}
{% block headline %}Notebook{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
<h2>Headline</h2>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="span8">

<form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit" />
</form>
    </div>

    </div>

{% endblock %}
```

And here's the attemtped extended form that would ideally contain both the form and the results:

```
{% extends 'report/write_note.html' %}


{% block extendscontent %}
    <div class="span4 offset8">
            {% if notes %}
            {% for note in user.notes.all reversed %}
             <h3>{{ note.title }}</h3>
             <p>{{ note.date }}</p>
             <p>{{ note.copy }}</p>
            {% endfor %}

            {% else %}
            <p>You have no notes stored.</p>

           {% endif %}
     </div>
 {% endblock extendscontent %}
```

And here are the views:

```
@login_required
def submit_note(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        notes_form = NotesForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if notes_form.is_valid():
            new_note = notes_form.save(commit=False)
            new_note.author = request.user
            new_note.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect( "" )
    else:
        notes_form = NotesForm()
    return render_to_response("report/write_note.html", {'form': notes_form},   context_instance=RequestContext(request))

@login_required
def all_notes(request):
    all_notes = Notes.objects.all().order_by('-date')
    paginate = paginated_stories(request, all_notes)
    return render_to_response("report/notes.html",
                           {'notes': paginate},
                            context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: You'll need to show the view.

Comment: Sorry, are you trying to use elements from one view in another view?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to place the "submit_notes" form in the same template as the "all_notes" one. That way users can see a list of their notes and submit a new one all on the same page.

Comment: But that doesn't make sense at all. How are you expecting the content from the `submit_notes` view to get into the template when it's called from `all_notes`?

Comment: So the view from the submit_notes template should be changed to render in the all_notes view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can have both form and notes on a same page by combining your views. ie  something like -

```
@login_required
def notes_view(request):
    all_notes = Notes.objects.all().order_by('-date')
    paginate = paginated_stories(request, all_notes)
    # form processing and other code
    # -------------------------------
    # return both form and notes to your template context
    return render_to_response("report/notes.html",{
        'notes': paginate,
        'form': notes_form,
    },context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Or you can create a custom `templatetag` either for rendering notes or notes_form

Comment: This worked great. Thanks for teaching me something! Was never quite sure how to combine a form and a response. Simple!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{% extends 'report/write_note.html' %}

{% block content %}
    {{ block.super }}

    <div class="span4 offset8">
            {% if notes %}
            {% for note in user.notes.all reversed %}
             <h3>{{ note.title }}</h3>
             <p>{{ note.date }}</p>
             <p>{{ note.copy }}</p>
            {% endfor %}

            {% else %}
            <p>You have no notes stored.</p>

           {% endif %}
     </div>
 {% endblock %}
```

When you're overriding a block you just override the block, you don't add "extends" to it.
And, `{{ block.super }}` can be used to get the content from the parent version of the block.

Comment: That was almost perfect! Except the form fields don't render, just the submit button. Otherwise, the notes also show up. Just need to figure out how to get the form to render.